# Running Java file with 2 args using perl script launched in Cygwin

Tags: java, perl, cygwin

I'm trying to write a Perl script to launch my Java program.

I'm trying to execute it using Cygwin in Windows 10.

The Java program's main method requires two arguments.

The main method looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    String ipAddress = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    ACPCGame acpc1 = new ACPCGame();
    acpc1.play(ipAddress, port);
}
```

I then have my Perl script called `canarybot.pl`.

```
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "canarybot.jar", "localhost", "55001");
system(@args);
```

`localhost` and `55001` are supposed to be the two arguments expected by the Java main method.

I then open a Cygwin bash prompt in the directory containing the Perl script and `jar` file and attempt to execute it like this

```
./canarybot.pl
```

This results in the error

> ./canarybot.pl: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token '('
>   ./canarybot.pl: line 1: my @args = ("java", "-jar", "canarybot.jar", "localhost', "55001");

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cygwin (any more) but: do you have a shebang line in your script (`#!/usr/bin/perl`)? And: does it work when you issue `perl ./canarybot.pl`?

Comment: I entirety of my script is posted above. I dont know what a shebang line is but I'll google it now.

Comment: The shebang line tells the system which program to use to interpret the rest of your script. In your case you want `perl` to process the script (as opposed to `bash` for example). Try adding the line `#!/usr/bin/perl` or just `#!perl` as the very first line to your script. (The two lines you show look good, btw.)

Comment: OK. That gets rid of the errors. But then nothing happens. I expect the java code to have some effect at that point. I will see if I can generate some output to an out file.

Comment: Does it work if you issue `java -jar canarybot.jar localhost 55001` from the Cygwin command line?

Comment: No. In that case it says - bash: java: command not found. I'm currently looking for java.exe and will try it with the full path

Comment: @Steve: Please tag your posts with e.g. `@Borodin` so that we get a notification of your comment. It sounds like you haven't installed Java on your system. You must do some basic debugging before you ask for free help. Every question and its answers here are supposed to be a a useful resource for the whole world. Please don't post monuments to carelessness.

Comment: @Steve: *Stack Overflow* is not a forum, and any question posted here should be relevant to everyone else who has encountered something similar. If you have a proper resolution and can explain it then please post it as an answer to your question. Please don't edit your question to include its own answer, and try to write your posts so that they are applicable to everyone with a similar problem who may arrive here via a search. I have rolled back your edit so that it contains just the most recent  version of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `syntax error near unexpected token` is a shell error. You are asking the Cygwin shell to execute a Perl program, and of course it makes nonsense in that context

You may use

```
    perl canarybot.pl
```

or you can add a
[*shebang line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

```
#!perl
```

to the start of your program, which will cause the Cygwin shell to look for `perl` on the PATH and use it to execute the subsequent code instead of trying to interpret it itself

But I don't see any reason to use Cygwin here. From the Windows `cmd` prompt you can use the command

```
canarybot.pl
```

Windows will start searching in the current working directory for the file, and the it will use the registry to determine how to process the `.pl` file type. There is no need for a shebang line at all

Comment: I used to use Cygwin as well years ago because it has a proper shell with tab-tab-tab-completion and other fancy things. I didn't care about how Windows would start my scripts because I started them from the Cygwin shell. Perhaps the OP is cast in the same mould. (I had to look up that phrase ;-))

Comment: If I run canarybot.pl from a cmd window it opens it in notepad :)

Comment: @PerlDuck: The most recent version of Windows 10 provides a bash shell. There is no longer any reason to use Cygwin, and if you're developing for Windows then you shouldn't assume a bash shell in the first place. Tribals will insist that you must pretend that your Windows platform is really a Linux system, but they are deluded.

Comment: @Steve: If `canarybot.pl` starts Notepad then your registry is messed up. Try `perl canarybot.pl`.

Comment: @Steve: Everything seems to surprise you. What *do* you know? Have you ever written a working program?

Comment: Yes, I've written some pretty good programs in java and c#. However, I'm totally unfamiliar with perl and command line stuff

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by editing the Perl script to use a shebang line along with an exact path to the java.exe file as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @args = ("/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java.exe", "-jar", "canarybot.jar", "localhost", "55001");
my $ret = system(@args);
```